# Unable to seek/replay video (.ogv) files served from http server [C#]

Tags: c#, video, webkit, ogg, httpserver

**ISSUE:** 
Video player (native player in webkit based browser) is not giving option to replay and I cannot seek video while playing it. Once played, I have to refresh page to play it again.
If I give a web url for ogv video in my html page, same player works fine (replays and seek is successful). 
Hence I suspect issue with my algorithm of serving files (especially .ogv files).

**What I am doing:**
I have an HTTP fileserver (completely in C#, using .Net framework classes - HttpListenerContext, HttpListenerRequest, HttpListenerResponse, etc). This server is serving files (of all types and extensions - text, video, audio, images) to clients. All files are available on server which are requested by clients.
Algorithm to serve files from server:

1. Server gets the file name from URL.
2. Reads the complete file in a buffer(byte[] array) (using File.ReadAllBytes(file_path_on_server)),
3. Array is assigned to HttpListenerResponse.OutputStream to return the file (contents) to client.
4. Corresponding HttpListenerResponse.ContentType (MimeType) and HttpListenerResponse.ContentLength64 is assigned (size of array).
5. Response header is added as "no-cache".
6. HttpListenerResponse.ContentEncoding is UTF8.
7. Close response object to send it to client.

This works fine and files are reaching clients for processing including video files (.ogv) but video is not seekable/replayable in player.

**Already tried**

- Tried removing assignment of HttpListenerResponse.ContentEncoding to UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you server returns the file the same way as if it's just downloaded, so seek/replay most likely will not be available until the whole file is loaded. If you want to support true video streaming you need another server-side implementation. Live Streaming within IIS Media Services may help you to support Apple HLS Streaming or similar (depending on your player), also i saw somewhere an IIS extension/module that supports http pseudo streaming with seeking for some video formats.